# Using Amazon S3 bucket and Cloudfront with an SSL Wordpress site doesn't serve the static files

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I have an ecommerce site running Wordpress with Divi Theme, and my site has its own SSL certificate.

I recently signed up for Amazon S3 and Cloudfront, and installed W3 Total Cache on my site. I've followed the online tutorials, and uploaded my site contents to my S3 bucket. However, when I click the option to use the CDN for my static files, the images on my site are not shown, and the theme goes a little wonky. I'm wondering if this is because my images are hosted in an 'https://' address? Would adding my SSL certificate to Cloudfront sort this, or is it something else? Any help on this one would be amazing.

Answer (score 0):

If you want users of you site to reference the name of images and content by https://example.com/images/image1.jpeg then yes you have to upload your cert to Cloudfront. otherwise you need to to reference them by the distrubution id,  https://d111111abcdef8.cloudfront.net/images/image1.jpeg.

[Requirements for a SSL cert on Cloudfront](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/cnames-and-https-requirements.html)

[SSL between Cloudfront and S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/using-https-cloudfront-to-s3-origin.html)

Note the following about using HTTPS when the origin is an Amazon S3 bucket:

> If your Amazon S3 bucket is configured as a website endpoint, you
>   can't configure CloudFront to use HTTPS to communicate with your
>   origin because Amazon S3 doesn't support HTTPS connections in that
>   configuration.
>
> Amazon S3 provides the SSL/TLS certificate, so you don't have to.